# progressive pdf download

Tags: objective-c, ipad, pdf, core-graphics

I want to download a pdf file progressively in an iPad application. I m not sure how to do that and google wasn't very helpful. can anyone help me understand the concepts here please. I am planning to render in core graphics.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean you want to render pdf pages before download is completed? If yes:

First of all, PDF format initially was not designed for that.

Let me explain. PDF file consists of a number of objects and xref. xref is a table containing location (in bytes from the beginning) of every object withing the file, so objects may be located at random locations withing the file. Even worse, xref itself is located at the end of file, so you can't locate any object in the file until you download it.

So, PDF is designed for random access. Actually, HTTP protocol allows it, so if you *really* need it, you can try to implement it :)

Good news for you: starting from PDF-1.2 there is a special feature called "Linearized PDF". It is designed exactly for your task, so you can render the first page before the next one if downloaded. You can google around or check out pdf reference for more details. The most important thing: you have to linearize pdf file using special tools, so not every pdf file can be rendered progressively.

Bad news for you: looks like core graphics doesn't support. I didn't tried it actually, but I found nothing re linearized pdf in core graphics documentation. (Please let me know if you will find anything.) So you may need to render PDF manually.

Comment: thanks for the answer. yes i want to render downloaded pages while downloading other pages. I will look at linearized PDF

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure about for iPad, but doing a Save as... in Acrobat by default it will be optimized as Fast Web View, which allows downloads a page at a time instead of the whole document in one go.

http://www.adobe.com/designcenter-archive/acrobat/articles/acr6optimize/acr6optimize.pdf

Answer (score 0):

[Linearzied PDF](http://mdn.morovia.com/manuals/pdfleo-1/PDF-Overview.php#Web-Optimized-Linearized-PDF) will meet your needs. You need a capable reader such as the one from Adobe to utilize this feature.

Comment: No, Sherwood Hu -- you need more than a *capable reader* to utilize this feature. You need the *linearized PDFs* in the first place. And in addition, you need a web server which supports the delivering of content in arbitrary chunks ('byte range' in HTTP-1.1). Now most modern web servers do support this. However, only a very small fraction of all real-world PDFs are made to be linear. If the OP's planned app is not designed for self-made PDFs only, then he can be made happy only with those downloaded PDFs which by accident are linearized already....