# Managing large PDF storaging and streaming

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, large-files, bandwidth

I'm going to build a java application on AWS stack which should manage big archives of large PDF files. Each PDF file could be of thousands of pages, usually aircrafts and aviation manuals.

I need to reorganize this content and stream for on demand use. I'm facing two big problems: bandwitch costs and complexity managements.
I'd like to split this manuals in least significant chapters and work with those. Does anyone know any tool (java API) which could be useful?

While, for the bandwitch problem I though I could use PDF linearitatio for streaming pages on demands and lowering output transmissions. What do you think about it? Am I wrong?

Thank you guys for your opinion and help.

Comment: Related question: [Printable Large PDF on the Web](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977648/printable-large-pdf-on-the-web/8978946#8978946)

Comment: What's "PDF linearitatio"?

Answer (score 2):

You should [linearize your PDFs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8928866/821436) and set up your service to use the linearization features (i.e. serve byte-ranges). And you should split your PDFs into small logical units. You should also research [dms](/questions/tagged/dms)(Document Management Systems) and [content-management-system](/questions/tagged/content-management-system).